# mysqldump: How to include index type?

Tags: mysql, index, backup, mysqldump

When I dump the schema of my database

```
mysqldump --no-data my_db > schema.sql
```

I get lines like this

```
KEY `index_tbl_on_col` (`col`)
```

but I want lines like this

```
KEY `index_tbl_on_col` (`col`) USING BTREE
```

The indexes in question do, in fact, have `Index_type = 'BTREE'`.

```
show index from tbl;
| Table | Key_name      | Index_type |
+-------+---------------+------------+
| tbl   | ix_tbl_on_col | BTREE      |
```

I have tried a variety of `mysqldump` options including using `--skip-opt --create-options` together.

I am using `mysqldump` 5.6.26 from [homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

```
mysqldump --version
mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.6.26, for osx10.10 (x86_64)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not worry about embedding the `USING BTREE` onto the indexes. Why ?

The default index type for MyISAM and InnoDB is BTREE. You cannot impose any other type.

The default index type for MEMORY Storage Engine is HASH. You can impose a BTREE index type.

I wrote a post 4 years ago on HASH not being allowed for MyISAM and InnoDB: [Why does MySQL not have hash indices on MyISAM or InnoDB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/why-does-mysql-not-have-hash-indices-on-myisam-or-innodb/2818#2818)

In light of this, there is no need to explicitly tack on `USING BTREE`.

You can look up the [`CREATE INDEX` Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-index.html) to verify default index types per Storage Engine.

## UPDATE 2015-09-24 16:23 EDT

Hey Jared, I got a surprise for you. I went Googling around and there is a way to spit out `USING BTREE`. The option is [--compatible=mysql40](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compatible). I saw it in StackOverflow : [MySQL error USING BTREE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3767831/491757)

Interestingly, [there is sort of a bug report on this. You know who submitted it ? A guy named Jared.](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25162)

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my question, but it is very useful.  I did not know that BTREE was the only supported index type in InnoDB, for example.  Thank you also for citing your sources.

Comment: mysqldump is not designed to display `USING BTREE`. I remember years ago that older versions mysqldump used to but they may have been source compiled. The standard versions don't do this.

Comment: I stand corrected by my own research. mysqldump can still dump `USING BTREE`.