# MySQL : Are hash indices useless?

Tags: mysql, database-recommendation, database-agnostic

In **MySQL**, hash indices are only supported by the `MEMORY` storage engine. By using this engine, data is stored in RAM, not on the hard disk, so it will be lost when MySQL is restarted.

Also, according to this link : [hash index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2817/why-does-mysql-not-have-hash-indices-on-myisam-or-innodb), it showed that hash indices are ineffective when data is stored on hard disk. But for practical usage for storing in RAM, **Redis** (other in-memory structures, .... ), may be a better choice than the `MEMORY` engine with MySQL.

So which use cases are valid for `MEMORY` storage engine and hash indices?

Answer (score 1):

A BTree index is arguably better than a Hash index.  A BTree can efficiently handle "ranges", whereas Hash is useless for such.  For "point queries" they are about equivalent.

As for `MEMORY`, the allure is the speed of access.  However, the caching of disk blocks makes any other Engine nearly as good in many production situations.

In a survey of over 1000 tables discussed on forums.mysql.com, only 6 were `MEMORY`.  I suggest that says that `MEMORY` is only very rarely the 'engine of choice'.

The lack of persistence makes `MEMORY` a non-starter.

As a "cache", Redis, memcached, Memory, etc, have appeal.  But InnoDB, for example, has a builtin cache, and it is usually inefficient to put a cache in front of a cache.

Perhaps you are thinking of some niche usage where `MEMORY` is well suited?

Comment: Yes, i want to know which cases someone want to use MEMORY instead of using other cache database ( redis, memcached , ... ). But can we control InnoDB cache ??? ( setting which query results should be saved, which columns, ...  ) . So i think it may be better if we using redis or other databases to stores query results , and control flow between redis and mysql in our codebase

Comment: Also consider whether you have embarked on "premature optimization".  Develop a prototype _without_ such a caching layer.  If it proves to be in adequate, _then_ talk about caching layers.